# Python subplots not working properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot three different graphs in three sub-plots within a single figure. Also I want the first figure to be of double width than the other two. Accordingly I have used

```
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[2,1], height_ratios=[1,1])
```

But the output has all the figures plotted on ax3.

[image]

My code is given here

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[2,1], height_ratios=[1,1])
ax1=plt.subplot(gs[:,:-1])
ax2=plt.subplot(gs[:-1,-1])
ax3=plt.subplot(gs[-1,-1])


# ax 1
X=np.linspace(0,10,100)
Y=np.sin(X)
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.scatter(X, Y)
ax1.axis("tight")
ax1.set_title('ax1')
ax1.set_xlim([0,10])
ax1.set_ylim([-1,1])
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])


# ax 2
ax2 = plt.gca()
vel=np.random.rand(1000)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(vel, 10, normed=True, histtype='stepfilled', facecolor='green', alpha=1.0)
ax2.set_title('Velocity Distribution')
ax2.axis("tight")
plt.xticks([0,0.05,0.10])
plt.yticks([0,10,20])


# ax 3
Z=np.exp(X)
ax3.plot(X,Z,'red',lw=5)

plt.show()
```

Can somebody tell me how I can rectify this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed several lines. Please compare with your code.

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec


gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, width_ratios=[2,1], height_ratios=[1,1])
ax1=plt.subplot(gs[:,:-1])
ax2=plt.subplot(gs[:-1,-1])
ax3=plt.subplot(gs[-1,-1])


# ax 1
X=np.linspace(0,10,100)
Y=np.sin(X)
#ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.scatter(X, Y)
ax1.axis("tight")
ax1.set_title('ax1')
ax1.set_xlim([0,10])
ax1.set_ylim([-1,1])
# You can use ax1.set_xticks() and ax1.set_xticklabels() instead.
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_yticks([])
#plt.xticks([])
#plt.yticks([])


# ax 2
#ax2 = plt.gca()
vel=np.random.rand(1000)
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(vel, 10, normed=True, histtype='stepfilled', facecolor='green', alpha=1.0)
ax2.set_title('Velocity Distribution')
ax2.axis("tight")
# You can use ax2.set_xticks() and ax2.set_xticklabels() instead.
ax2.set_xticks([0,0.5,1])
ax2.set_yticks([0,1,2])
#plt.xticks([0,0.05,0.10])
#plt.yticks([0,10,20])


# ax 3
Z=np.exp(X)
ax3.plot(X, Z,'red', lw=5)
# You can use ax3.set_xticks() and ax3.set_xticklabels() instead.
ax3.set_xticks([0, 5, 10])
ax3.set_yticks([0, 10000, 20000])
ax3.set_yticklabels(['0', '10K', '20K'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works. On a first check I noticed that you have removed the lines `ax2 = plt.gca()`. May I ask why they are not necessary. Or what they do in other places where they are used?

Comment: @kanayamalakar You assigned `ax3=plt.subplot(gs[-1,-1])` for the last ax of those three axes. But right after that there was `ax1 = plt.gca()`. `gca()` means get_current_axes. Hence it works like `ax3 = ax1`. That's the reason of all axes plotted at ax3.

Comment: @kanayamalakar Improved answer little bit more on ax3 ticks. Use `sca()` to access just one subplot.

Comment: if you are using the object-oriented approach, why not use it everywhere? I.e., remove the `plt.xticks()`  and `plt.yticks()` calls, and use `ax1.set_xticks()` and `ax1.set_xticklabels()`, etc. Then there's no need for `sca()` and you remove any source of confusion - your ticks and labels will always be on the axes you expect them to be on!

Comment: Okay I got that now ! And thanks @tom for your help.